# Add a Switch to Navigation Bar using Storyboard

Tags: ios, navigationbar, uiswitch

I'm trying to add a `Switch` as `UINavigationBar` Item through my storyboard. The problem is that when I connect to outlet or action. There is only 1 choice (`UIBarItem`) and no Switch Item. How can we add switch to `UINavigationBar` and control the on off state?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switch is inside the `BarButtonItem`. Find it in the hierarchy and drag from there.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not notice. further more how can we arrange the position of the navibarbutton? in code? (for ex we want to swap between switch and refresh

Comment: Yes, `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton`